# Code Coverage Mismatch for Junits between Intellij and MVN

Tags: java, maven, junit, code-coverage, clover

I am using Coverage Plugin of Intellij, and getting between 95-100% coverage for all classes.

But, when I do *mvn clean install*

I get the following error

[ERROR] Total coverage of 73.1% did not meet target of 80%

[ERROR] Method coverage of 77.8% did not meet target of 80%

[ERROR] Statement coverage of 64.3% did not meet target of 80%

.

..unable to find a reason for the coverage percentage mismatch.

Comment: The question is what kind of code coverage you are using in your maven build?

Comment: Maybe IntelliJ excludes some classes and/or packages (like DTOs) where test coverage is not meaningful?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using CLOVER coverage

Comment: In IntelliJ there are two coverage tools part of. First one the IntelliJ Coverage and JaCoCo...You should make sure to use the same coverage tool otherwise you will always have differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the issue...

I was using JUPITER library for writing test cases at few files of mine.

I removed **Jupiter** library.
Instead used **JUnit** library.

..and with same test cases, surprisingly was able to meet the coverage !!!